# How to use multiple $lookup with arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

let's consider i have some collection and the structures of data is look like these

**post col:**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5fce0e137ff7401634bad2ac")
    address: "new york"
    description: "this is a great city"
    image: "images\0.4644859674390589-gikiguk.jpg"
    userId: "5fcdcd8487e37216bc82171b"
}
```

**user col:**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5fcdcd8487e37216bc82171b")
    name: "jack"
    profile: {image: "images\0.4644859674390589-dofowfg.jpg", description: "be happy dude"}
    email: "test@test.com"
    password: "2a$12$gzRrY83QAjwLhdyvn3JQ2OcMj3XG65.BULva4cZqcuSxDhhMbSXCq"
}
```

**likesComments col:**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5fce0e191ff7301666kao2xc")
    likes: {quantity: 1, likes: [{isActive: true, userId: "5fcdcd8487c31216cc87886r"}]}
    comments: {quantity: 1, comments: [{userId: "5fcdcd8487c31216cc87886r" , comment: "awesome city"}]}
    postId: "5fce0e137ff7401634bad2ac"
}
```

what i want to do is i have a userId (maybe more than one) that i want to search through all of posts (that is belong to the user) and get some data from `posts collection` and then `$lookup` to `users collection` that again get some data about user and after that every post has own `postId`  (i converted `_id` to `postId`). with `postId` i can  `$lookup` to `likeComments documents` and get some data about any posts, but if a post don't have any likes or comments, all of my query that i wrote them gives me an empty array `[]` (not data at all just empty array) but if a post has at least one like and one comment, all of my query works find.

what i expect is something like this:

```
    [
      {
        postId: '5fce0e137ff7401634bad2ac',    //from post
        location: 'shiraz', // from post
        description: 'this is a greate city',    // from post
        image: 'images\\0.4644859674390589-gikiguk.jpg',    // from post
        userId: '5fcdcd8487e37216bc82171b',    // from user
        name: 'mohammad',    // from user
        profile: 'images\\0.6093033055735912-DSC_0002_2.JPG',    // from user
        comments: { quantity: 1, comments: [{userId: "...", name: "...", profile: "...", comment: "..."}] },    // from likesComments and then lookup to users documets to get data about users that wrote comments
        likes: {quantity: 1, [{userId: "...", name: "...", profile: "..."}]}    // from likesCommnets and then lookup to users documets to get data about users that liked the post
      }
    ]
```

**query:**

i know that my query is wrong but i can't find what's wrong here.

```
db.collection("posts")
          .aggregate([
            { $match: { userId: { $in: users.map(u => u) } } },
            {
              $project: {
                _id: 0,
                userId: { $toObjectId: "$userId" },
                postId: { $toString: "$_id" },
                location: "$address",
                description: "$description",
                image: "$image"
              }
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "userId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "userInfo"
              }
            },
            { $unwind: "$userInfo" },
            {
              $project: {
                _id: 0,
                postId: 1,
                location: 1,
                description: 1,
                image: 1,
                userId: { $toString: "$userId" },
                name: "$userInfo.name",
                profile: "$userInfo.profile.image"
              }
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "likes-comments",
                localField: "postId",
                foreignField: "postId",
                as: "likesComments"
              }
            },
            { $unwind: "$likesComments" },
            {
              $project: {
                postId: 1,
                location: 1,
                description: 1,
                image: 1,
                userId: 1,
                name: 1,
                profile: 1,
                likes: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$likesComments.likes.likes",
                    as: "item",
                    in: {
                      $toObjectId: "$$item.userId"
                    }
                  }
                },
                quantity: "$likesComments.comments.quantity",
                comments: {
                  comments: {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$likesComments.comments.comments",
                      as: "item",
                      in: {
                        $toObjectId: "$$item.userId"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "likes",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "likes"
              }
            },
            { $unwind: "$likes" },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "comments.comments",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "comments"
              }
            },
            { $unwind: "$comments" },
            { $addFields: { quantity: "$quantity" } },
            {
              $project: {
                _id: 0,
                postId: 1,
                location: 1,
                description: 1,
                image: 1,
                userId: 1,
                name: 1,
                profile: 1,
                likes: [
                  {
                    userId: { $toString: "$likes._id" },
                    name: "$likes.name",
                    profile: "$likes.profile.image"
                  }
                ],
                comments: {
                  quantity: 1,
                  comments: [
                    {
                      userId: { $toString: "$comments._id" },
                      name: "$comments.name",
                      profile: "$comments.profile.image"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ])
          .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your example:

1. check the collection names when $lookup. There are multiple discrepancies with your collection names.
2. check out the `types` and `names` of $lookup fields. Some of the ids are in string while some of them are in ObjectId. This will cause invalid lookup. You may need to use sub queries in $lookup for type conversion before lookup.
3. Some of your ObjectIds contains non-hex characters(e.g. `_id` of `likeComments`)
4. data issue in the example; some of the id just does not match.(e.g. `likeComments.likes.likes.userId` vs `user._id`)

Here is the [FIRST HALF](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RNuOJm-zzyv) of your pipeline with fixes to part of the above issues. You may want to use as a reference to fix the remaining issues.